# Oneliner to run an adhock webserver in python or node.js that serves up rendered markdown from the current directory?

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, webserver, markdown

I know there's a oneliner to serve up the current directory from Python 3 or node.js from a specified port, is there a oneliner to do the same thing, but render the Mark Down (`.md`) files from the webserver generated by the oneliner?

Comment: This sort of thing would require a third party [static site generator](https://www.staticgen.com/).

Comment: I'm removing the oneliner tag, as it's not a good fit for the tag system, after a short discussion in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). If you disagree, feel free to contact me using chat.